# Tensorflow: When to stop training due to the best (minimum) cost?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am using TensorFlow to classify images using LeNet network. I use AdamOptimizer to minimize the cost function. When I start to train the model, I can observe that the training accuracy and validation accuracy and also the cost is changing, sometimes reducing and sometimes increasing.

**My questions**: When should we stop the training? How can we know that the optimizer will find the minimum cost? how many iterations should we do the training? Can we set a variable or condition to stop at the minimum cost?

**My solution** is to define a global variable (min_cost) and in each iteration check if the cost is reducing then save the session and replace the min_cost with the new cost. At the end, I will have the saved session for the minimum cost,

Is this a correct approach?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

While training neural networks, mostly a target error is defined alongside with a maximum amount of iterations to train. So for example, a target error could be `0.001MSE`. Once this error has been reached, the training will stop - if this error has not been reached after the maximum amount of iterations, the training will also stop.

But it seems like you want to train until you know the network can't do any better. Saving the 'best' parameters like you're doing is a fine approach, but do realise that once some kind of minimum cost has been reached, the error won't fluctuate that much anymore. It won't be like the error suddenly goes up significantly, so it is not completely necessary to save the network.

There is no such thing as 'minimal cost' - the network is always trying to go to some local minima, and it will always be doing so. There is not really way you (or an algorithm) can figure out that there is no better error to be reached anymore.

tl;dr - just set a target reasonable target error alongside with a maximum amount of iterations.

Comment: So, in the first paragraph, you said that I need to train the model for a very high number of iteration and it will converge at some point, right?

Comment: Well the thing is, you have to set a reasonable error target - the number of iterations should just be an amount of which you know that the network should have converged to the minima. The max iterations is a fallback of the target error.

Comment: Therefore, I should find the max iteration and the target error by trial-and-error approach?

Comment: Yes basically, but i have to note that your first comment is correct: setting the maximum iterations to a high value will mean that the network will have converged as much as possible, as the error wont go up or doen significantly amymore after a high no. of iterations.